# A Paley-Wiener theorem.

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, harmonic-analysis

In *Lund, John, and Kenneth L. Bowers. Sinc methods for quadrature and differential equations. SIAM, 1992.* is recalled a Paley-Wiener theorem, as follows:

> Assume that f is entire and $f \in L^2(\mathbb R)$. If there are
>   positive constant K so that for all $z\in\mathbb C$ $$|f(z)|\leq K
>  e^{\pi |z|},$$ then $\mathcal F(f)\in
>  L^2(-\pi,\pi)$ and $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \mathcal
>  F(f)(x) e^{-ixz}dx.$$
>   where $\mathcal F(f)$ is the Fourier transform of $f$.

This theorem is stated without proof. I would get an answer that contains this proof, or a reference (online or not) where we can find it.

Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, this is proven in "Rudin: functional analysis", but maybe my memory is wrong.

Comment: I believe it is in Stein and Weiss, Introduction to Fourier Analysis on Euclidean Spaces, Chapter 3.4.

Comment: I will search these books. Thank you!